# How do we know that every n-dimensional over $\Bbb R$ is isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading a paper on linear mappings and it implies without proof that every pair of n-dimensional vector spaces over the reals, $\Bbb U$ and $\Bbb V$, are isomorphic.  How would one prove this?  Is it also true, more generally, that any 2 vector spaces of the same dimension over the same field (not necessarily $\Bbb R$) are isomorphic?

Also is there a *canonical* isomorphism?

Comment: The answer is yes. It's proved in any linear algebra book.

Comment: There is not, in general, a canonical isomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

Two vector spaces over the same field are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension. To prove the implication you're interested in, pick a bijection between bases and extend it linearly. It's an easy exercise that this is indeed an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

- Let Basis of $U$ be $\{u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n\}$
- Let Basis of $V$ be $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$

Consider $\eta :U\rightarrow V$ sending $u_i$ to $v_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$